# Combining arrays element wise to form an array of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I am struggling to figure out this code.

Essentially, I want to create two arrays, N-1 by 1, of which contain random numbers between -2 and 2. I then want to combine these arrays element-wise, to form a new array of pairs of coordinates.

Here is the code I have so far, but I am not sure how to finish it (I am using numpy).

```
def x0x1Array(N):
    
    x0x1 = np.zeros([N-1, 1])
    x0 = np.zeros([N-1, 1])
    x1 = np.zeros([N-1, 1])
    
    x1 = np.zeros([1, N-1])
    
    for i in range(0, len(x0)):
        for j in range(0, len(x1)):
                x0[i] = np.random.uniform(-2,2)
                x1[j] = np.random.uniform(-2,2)
                
    x0x1 = np.array((x0,x1)).T
                
    print(x0x1)
```

Hope you guys can help!

O it worked, i just took a transpose!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to make this more efficient just by using the fact that [`np.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) can generate entire arrays at a time, not just one element at a time:

```
x0x1 = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, size = (N,2))
```

You can then, if you need to, access each column with:

```
x0 = x0x1[:,0]
x1 = x0x1[:,1]
```

Comment: And note that the documentation actually suggests using a [`Generator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#random-quick-start) object as opposed to the base `uniform` method: `x0x1 = np.random.default_rng().uniform(-2, 2, size = (N,2))`

Comment: Many thanks! This will help!

Comment: I just have a quick question I have this line of code

     vectorZ = x0 + F*(x1-x2)

All inputs here are vectors of two elements. I was wondering what the easiest way was to do vector addition, multiplication and subtraction in this one line of code?

Many thanks.

Comment: For MOST operations, like adding and subtracting, numpy arrays do operations element-by-element (exactly like you want vectors to add and subtract, plus you can do a whole bunch at once). So you can use that exact line of code, and if x0, x1, and x2 are all arrays of shape (N,2), then it'll work as if you're calculating that equation for N different vectors. Plus, if F is just some number, you CAN multiply like in that line of code and it'll multiply like you'd want vectors to (and if F is different for each vector equation, F can also be an array of shape (N))

Comment: Yes, so all the inputs have the same shape, x0, x1, x2. They are just random choice vectors from my initial coordinate vector. Then since this is so, I can just leave the line as it is? F is just 0.8.

Comment: Yup! But in general, if you're ever in doubt, it's always helpful to go through the code with toy inputs (with values like [1,2,3,4,5] and such that are easy to do the math with by hand) so that you can see what's happening at every step and can tell if it's doing what it should be

Comment: Especially for array stuff, I'd suggest looking at the numpy [quick start page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#prerequisites) (and the rest of the documentation) to get a feel for what you can/can't do